# Gravitational potential for concentric spherical shells

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

I am trying to understand some calculations related to the model for spherical collapse in cosmology, arising from an overdense region of the universe. In this model we have a sphere that has a fixed mass and is uniform, which is considered as foliated into concentric spherical shells.

The energy conservation equation for a shell of radius $r$ is stated to be the following:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2-\dfrac{GM}{r}=E$$

where $M$ is the mass enclosed inside the shell. First, I assume that this equation is actually:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}(dm)\dot{r}^2-\dfrac{GM(dm)}{r}=E\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \dfrac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2-\dfrac{GM}{r}=\dfrac{E}{dm}\equiv E$$

where $dm$ is the infinitesimal mass of the shell and $E/dm$ is renamed as $E$ for simplicity. Am I correct?

And second, I don't understand why the gravitational potential is calculated taking only into account the mass enclosed by the shell. What happens with the mass of the sphere that is outside the shell, that is, the mass for which $r_m>r$ with $r$ the radius of the shell? Doesn't this mass exert a gravitational force on the shell, too, thus modifying the gravitational potential?

Comment: The potential for the interior of a symmetric shell is constant for inverse square laws, this is the same as it is for electrostatics. Thus the field associated is zero on the interior.

Comment: @Triatticus Thank you! So, the gravitational potential caused on the shell by the mass that is outside of it is constant, and therefore it can be included in the constant $E$, right? I suppose it is easy to see mathematically from the symmetry of the situation, but I'm not sure how to write it formally.